# How to fetch sum of records with respect to date in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
            col1      col2
           | 2015-02-01  12 
           | 2015-02-01  10 
           | 2015-02-01   5 
           | 2015-02-02   8 
           | 2015-02-03  25 
           | 2015-02-03  10 
           | 2015-02-04  20
```

Above is the sample of the table i have. i want to achieve sum of col2 with respect to date given a specified range.
 say if i fetch sum(col2) records between dates 01-02-2015 to 03-02-2015, then my output should be,

```
           | 2015-02-01  27 
           | 2015-02-02   8 
           | 2015-02-03  35
```

Is it possible to achieve this in mysql?

Comment: Hint use `sum()` with `group by`

Comment: Example query is `SELECT col1, sum(col2) as col2 FROM myTable GROUP BY col1` where `myTable` is your table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If col1 is a DATE column, you can use this query:

```
SELECT   col1, SUM(col2) AS sum_of_col2
FROM     tablename
WHERE    col1 BETWEEN '2015-02-01' AND '2015-02-03'
GROUP BY col1
```

If col1 is a DATETIME column, and contains DATE but also TIME informations, you should use this:

```
SELECT
  DATE(col1) AS date_of_col1,
  SUM(col2) AS sum_of_col2
FROM
  tablename
WHERE
  col1>='2015-02-01' AND
  col1<'2015-02-03' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY
  DATE(col1)
```

Comment: thank you so much :) this is what i expected. i get the answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(col2) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE col1 BETWEEN '2015-02-01' AND '2015-02-03'
GROUP BY col1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by with between [clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) to get your answer:

```
 SELECT col1, sum(col2) as col2 FROM test where col1 BETWEEN '01-02-15' AND '03-02-15' GROUP BY col1
```